# Is it possible to compress js files with next export?

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js, compression, amazon-cloudfront

I'm not very familiar with compressing, but Google PageSpeed insights showing a huge red sign for it.

I'm using an S3 bucket where I export my nextjs static files, and serve them with CloudFront from there.

I tried setting the line in `next.config.js`: `compress: true,`, but it dones't seem to work.

Is it possible to compress js files to gzip when exporting, and is there a built in method in nextjs to do so?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use AWS Cloudfront you need to provided with minified JS files.

Publish the built output of your nextJS project to AWS S3.

AWS Cloudfront is just CDN the serve web assets, ready to consume.